# convert ipv4 netmask to cidr format

Tags: php, networking, ip, ipv4, cidr

I have the ip and netmask

```
192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

I need to convert the netmask into cidr format

```
192.168.1.0/24
```

How do I convert ipv4 address and netmask into cidr format?

I am using PHP5.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complicated way would be to convert the netmask to binary and count the number of leading 1 bits. But since there are only 33 possible values, a simpler way is just an associative array:

```
$netmask_to_cidr = array(
    '255.255.255.255' => 32,
    '255.255.255.254' => 31,
    '255.255.255.252' => 30,
    ...
    '128.0.0.0' => 1,
    '0.0.0.0' => 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit hold the topic, but may help someone else and you have here the solution:

```
function mask2cidr($mask)
{
  $long = ip2long($mask);
  $base = ip2long('255.255.255.255');
  return 32-log(($long ^ $base)+1,2);

  /* xor-ing will give you the inverse mask,
      log base 2 of that +1 will return the number
      of bits that are off in the mask and subtracting
      from 32 gets you the cidr notation */
}
```

[PHP ip2long help](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ip2long.php)

Comment: You'll get `INF` result for `0.0.0.0` mask

Answer (score 1):

The following code transfers the mask to binary to convert the binary to CIDR

```php
    public function mask2cdr($mask) {
          $dq = explode(".",$mask);
          for ($i=0; $i<4 ; $i++) {
             $bin[$i]=str_pad(decbin($dq[$i]), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
          }
          $bin = implode("",$bin); 

          return strlen(rtrim($bin,"0"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code from [php ip2long help](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ip2long.php) for `0.0.0.0` mask and simplified it a little (no need to always compute `$base = ip2long('255.255.255.255');`):

```
function mask2cidr($mask)
{
    if($mask[0]=='0')
        return 0;

    return 32 - log(~ip2long($mask) + 1, 2);
}
```

@Barmar's answer is good too, as it will always do the job without any surprises on any PC architecture.

Comment: `~` doesn't seem to exist anymore in PHP.

Comment: Bitwise negation most certainly still does exist in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

```
function convert($ip,$mask){
  return $ip."/".strlen(str_replace("0","",decbin(ip2long($mask))))
}
```